# I want to find a file of a specific extension using readdir (async) with recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, filesystems

I am new in Node js and i have a task to create cli utility for search files by extension.
i write this

```
const fs = require('fs');  
const path = require('path'); 

let pathSupplied = './';
let extFilter = 'html';

function extension(element) {
    let extName = path.extname(element);
    return extName === '.' + extFilter;
};

let walk = function (dir, done) {
    let result = []
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
        list.forEach((item) => {
            let itemPath = path.join(dir, item);
            fs.stat(itemPath, (e, stats) => {
                console.log(itemPath);
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(itemPath);
                } else {
                    list.filter(extension).forEach(function (value) {
                        console.log(value);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
}
```

It works, but not the way I want. At the output, I get files with the html extension but they are duplicated.
How can I fix this?
And how can I write the result to the array?

Comment: They are duplicated because you log them twice : `console.log(itemPath);` and `console.log(value);`

Comment: To store the result in an array, the simpliest way would be to declare a global one and `push` the `value` in `list.filter(extension).forEach(function (value) { ... }`

Comment: i deleted console.log (itemPath); but nothing changed

Comment: You are iterating twice the list of files/folders : `list.forEach((item) => {` and later, inside that loop : `list.filter(extension).forEach(function (value) {`

Comment: You might want to replace `list.filter(extension).forEach(function (value) {` by `if (extension(itemPath)) {`

Comment: I tried to declare the array globally and push the result into it, but then when I output it it was empty. how to write this function correctly?

Comment: I replaced list.filter with if now everything outputs normally without duplicates but it doesn’t turn out to write the result to an array

Comment: My bet is you delclared twice the array

Comment: i deleted result in function and add befor function and add results.push(item Path) in if statement
but after calling function i calling console.log (results) but it empty

Answer (score 0):

This is a natural to use promises and `async/await` as it makes the coding a lot, lot simpler.  I'd suggest creating a generic `walk()` function that you can pass a callback to that will get called for each file in the hierarchy.  You can then use that callback to collect any results you want.

If you don't pass a callback, then it just resolves to an array of all the filenames it found.

Here's the generic walk function:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

async function walk(dir, callback, results = []) {
    let files = await fsp.readdir(dir, {withFileTypes: true});
    let dirs = [];
    for (let file of files) {
        let fullPath = path.join(dir, file.name);
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (callback) {
                let r = await callback(fullPath);
                if (r !== undefined) {
                    results.push(r);
                }
             } else {
                // no callback, just collect the file into the results
                results.push(fullPath);
             }
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // save this until we're done with files
            dirs.push(fullPath);
        }
    }
    for (let d of dirs) {
        await walk(d, callback, results);
    }
    return results;
}
```

And, then you could accumulate files with a specific extension by using it like this:

```
const targetExt = ".html";
const someTopDir = "D:/somepath/somedir";

walk(someTopDir, function(file) {
    if (path.extname(file) === targetExt) {
        return file;
    }
}).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Some notes about the implementation:

1. The callback can optionally be asynchronous if it returns a promise.
2. This uses the fsPromises API from recent versions of node.js for promisified versions of many fs library functions.
3. This leverages the newer `withFileTypes` option for `readdir()` which saves an asynchronous operation on each file to test for it being a directory
4. Any error anywhere in the chain will abort the whole chain and bubble up to the caller as a rejected promise.
5. The `walk()` function returns a promise that resolves to an array of values that your callback returned.  This means you can use it like a combination of `.map()` and `.filter()`.  The input array is an array of all the files in the directory hierarchy.  If your callback returns `undefined`, then nothing is present in the output for that particular file (kind of like `.filter()`).  If the callback returns anything other than `undefined`, then that return value will be in the output array (kind of like `.map()`).   In this particular callback implementation it checks to see if the file extension is a matching extension.  If so, it just returns that filename (to include it in the output).  If not, it doesn't return anything (which means the return value is `undefined`) so nothing is included in the output for that file.  It essentially allows you to do a `.map()` and a `.filter()` at once.

Comment: @Name - Was this useful to you?